# FB.Init no callback for some users

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to add Facebook functionality to my Unity3D project, which is working for me. But for some unknown reason the test scene doesn't seem to work for some Facebook users. It looks like the the Facebook DLL doesn't load.

I'm using the example scene which comes with Unity3D Facebook SDK. No modifications, I only changed the App Name and App Id (Facebook Settings).

The application is set on public.

log when it works:

```
140505 15:36:05 ------------------------------------------------------------
140505 15:36:05 Instance starting, version 4.3.5f1_cab656801c19, UNITY_WEB_ENABLE_AUTODOWNLOAD: 1, GetDisableAutoUpdates(): 0
140505 15:36:05 Datafile https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~vriens09/facebook.unity3d
web: player version 4.3.6f1
web: load mono
Mono path[0] = 'C:/Users/Robert/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/player/Stable3.x.x/Data/lib'
Mono path[1] = 'C:/Users/Robert/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/mono/Stable3.x.x/Data/lib'
Mono config path = 'C:/Users/Robert/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/mono/Stable3.x.x/Data/etc'
web: start, src=https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~vriens09/facebook.unity3d abs=https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~vriens09/facebook.unity3d flags=0x1
web: sucessfully initialized
140505 15:36:06 loader: start ok
140505 15:36:06 Times: download 0.2 load 0.1
Loading webdata version: 4.3.4f1
Initialize engine version: 4.3.6f1 (7a73f0242edf)
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=0
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 9.0c [nvd3dum.dll 9.18.13.3250]
    Renderer: NVIDIA Quadro FX 570M
    Vendor:   NVIDIA
    VRAM:     1255 MB (via DXGI)
    Caps:     Shader=30 DepthRT=1 NativeDepth=1 NativeShadow=1 DF16=0 INTZ=1 RAWZ=0 NULL=1 RESZ=0 SlowINTZ=0
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\Data\lib\UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Robert\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\IFacebook.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Robert\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\IFacebook.dll into Unity Child Domain
- Completed reload, in  0.074 seconds
<RI> Initializing input.

<RI> Input initialized.

desktop: 1680x1050 60Hz; virtual: 1680x1050 at 0,0
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\mono\Stable3.x.x\Data\lib\System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Using SDK 5.1.0, Build 140401.725cc2ecbc9002a

(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/WebPlayerGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 53)

Platform assembly: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\Data\lib\CrossDomainPolicyParser.dll (this message is harmless)
loading dll: /rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_5.1/CanvasFacebook.dll

(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/WebPlayerGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 53)

Platform assembly: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\mono\Stable3.x.x\Data\lib\Mono.Security.dll (this message is harmless)
Non platform assembly: data-0B170078 (this message is harmless)
Finished loading Facebook dll. Version 5.1.0 Build 140313.f19caa5422b69ba

(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/WebPlayerGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 53)

FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? True

(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/WebPlayerGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 53)

Platform assembly: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\mono\Stable3.x.x\Data\lib\System.dll (this message is harmless)
```

log when it fails:

```
140505 15:33:35 ------------------------------------------------------------
140505 15:33:35 Instance starting, version 4.3.5f1_cab656801c19, UNITY_WEB_ENABLE_AUTODOWNLOAD: 1, GetDisableAutoUpdates(): 0
140505 15:33:36 Datafile https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~vriens09/facebook.unity3d
web: player version 4.3.6f1
web: load mono
Mono path[0] = 'C:/Users/Eigenaar/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/player/Stable3.x.x/Data/lib'
Mono path[1] = 'C:/Users/Eigenaar/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/mono/Stable3.x.x/Data/lib'
Mono config path = 'C:/Users/Eigenaar/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/mono/Stable3.x.x/Data/etc'
web: start, src=https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~vriens09/facebook.unity3dabs=https://oege.ie.hva.nl/~vriens09/facebook.unity3d flags=0x1
web: sucessfully initialized
140505 15:33:36 loader: start ok
140505 15:33:36 Times: download 0.7 load 0.2
Loading webdata version: 4.3.4f1
Initialize engine version: 4.3.6f1 (7a73f0242edf)
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=0
Direct3D:
    Version: Direct3D 9.0c [igdumd32.dll 8.15.10.1749]
    Renderer: Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)
    Vendor: Intel
    VRAM: 64 MB (via DXGI)
    Caps: Shader=30 DepthRT=1 NativeDepth=0 NativeShadow=1 DF16=0 INTZ=0 RAWZ=0 NULL=0 RESZ=0 SlowINTZ=0
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\Data\lib\UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\IFacebook.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\IFacebook.dll into Unity Child Domain
- Completed reload, in 0.119 seconds
<RI> Initializing input.

XInput1_3.dll not found.
<RI> Input initialized.

desktop: 1280x800 60Hz; virtual: 1280x800 at 0,0
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\mono\Stable3.x.x\Data\lib\System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Using SDK 5.1.0, Build 140401.725cc2ecbc9002a

(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/WebPlayerGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 53)

Platform assembly: C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\player\Stable3.x.x\Data\lib\CrossDomainPolicyParser.dll (this message is harmless)
loading dll: /rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_5.1/CanvasFacebook.dll

(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/WebPlayerGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 53)

Platform assembly: C:\Users\Eigenaar\AppData\LocalLow\Unity\WebPlayer\mono\Stable3.x.x\Data\lib\Mono.Security.dll (this message is harmless)
Non platform assembly: data-09B0B848 (this message is harmless)
Finished loading Facebook dll. Version 5.1.0 Build 140313.f19caa5422b69ba

(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/WebPlayerGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 53)
```

- SDK Version 5.1.0
- Unity3D Version 4.3.4f1

Comment: It appears that notrace extension was the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you get over it ?

Comment: The reason why it didnt worked cause donottrackme was blocking the api